# Properties file for slf4j not read even though on classpath

Tags: java, classpath, slf4j, properties-file

In sl4j [SimpleLogger documentation](http://www.slf4j.org/api/org/slf4j/impl/SimpleLogger.html) it says that if you have a file named simplelogger.properties it should be loaded automatically. I can't get it to work (load). There must be something obvious I'm missing?

The contents of the simplelogger.properties:

```
org.slf4j.simpleLogger.logFile=./logfiletxt
org.slf4j.simpleLogger.showLogName=false
```

When I change the logfile-property as a parameter (-D) it works, that is, it logs to my logfile and not in the console (as can be seen below).

I have a very simple project setup, and I have placed the file in the project root, which, as I understand, is the default classpath. Please see the attached pictures.

The file in the folder
[image: The file in the folder]

The classpath
[image: The classpath]

Runtime results shows it's not working
[image: Runtime results shows it's not working]

Comment: What aspect of the logging isn't working? You seem to be printing out system properties which haven't been defined, hence they are `null`.

Comment: You are right, I forgot to show the contents of simplelogger.propertis. It should log to a logfile instead of the console. I have updated the question.

Answer (score -1):

You can put the simplelogger.properties into the src of your project

[image]